# Cartesian Product of Interval

Tags: interval-arithmetic

I know what is a cartesian product of sets, for example, $M= \{1,2\} , N = \{a,b\} $

$M \times N  =  {(1,a), (1,b), (2,a) , (2,b)}$

but what is the Cartesian product of two intervals? say,

$[-5,1] \times [-2,3]$

Comment: It's the square defined by those intervals. $(-5,-2)$ is the lower left corner and $(1,3)$ the upper right. Set of ordered pairs, one from the first set, the other from the second set. Intervals are sets.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By definition it is the set of couple:
$$
\{(x,y)|x\in[-5,1]\land y\in[-2,3] \}
$$
so it the rectangle $EFGH$ in the figure.
[image]